# How to find integral of $(-1)^x$?

Tags: calculus, integration

According to Wolfram Alpha, 
$$\int (-1)^x\, dx = -\frac{i}{\pi} (-1)^x   + C$$
How to find it out manually?

Comment: I think you typed it in wrong. Anyways, do you realize $(-1)^x$ is a complex-valued multi-valued function?

Comment: @Hurkyl, Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Did you try writing $a^x$ as $\exp(x\log(a))$?

Comment: I bet wolfram added an arbitrary constant too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $$(-1)^x=(e^{i\pi})^x=e^{i\pi x}$$
Then $$\int e^{i\pi x} dx$$
Substitute $$u=i\pi x, du=i\pi dx$$
$$-\frac {i}{\pi} \int e^u du = - \frac {i e^{i\pi x}}{\pi} +c$$

I think you typed int -1^x dx in W|A which is interpreted as $\int -(1^x) dx$ so it evaluated $\int -1 dx$.

Answer (score 4):

Use $-1=e^{i\pi}$ and the chain rule.